# Automatic type casting

Tags: java, casting

I have a program that needs to accept objects of which the class types are only known at runtime.  I was wondering if it's possible to have the program automatically cast back the objects to the correct class type?

The following code is what I currently have; I will explain what I expect it to do step-by-step:

1. Create a `TryingSomething` instance that adds two sets (one of class type `Foo`, one of class type `Bar`).
2. The sets are supposed to be added to the hashmap. At this point I already get a warning from Eclipse, warning me that the sets are not compatible somehow. The types are the same though.  What went wrong here?
3. Moving on, assuming the previous step did work as intended. I wish to retrieve the collections in the main method again, but already cast to the correct class types (`Foo` and `Bar`).  Will this work?  If not, is there an alternative that allows me to retrieve the objects back in their correct class type?
4. *(Bonus)* The name String that's attached with each collection, is introduced to allow me to distinguish between the different class types.  It would be even better if it was possible to achieve the results in step 3, without needing the String.

Thanks to anyone who can give me some pointers.

```
class TryingSomething<T> {
    private Map<String, Set<T>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<T>>();

    public void addCollection(Set<T> s, String name){
        this.map.put(name, s);
    }

    public void test(){
        Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>();
        Set<Bar> bar = new HashSet<Bar>();
        addCollection(foo, "foo");
        addCollection(bar, "bar");
    }

    public Set<T> getCollections(String name){
        return this.map.get(name);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args){
        TryingSomething t = new TryingSomething();
        Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>();
        Set<Bar> bar = new HashSet<Bar>();
        t.addCollection(foo, "foo");
        t.addCollection(bar, "bar");
        Set<Foo> fooList = t.getCollections("foo");
        Set<Bar> barList = t.getCollections("bar");
    }

}

class Foo{
}

class Bar{
}
```

Comment: For starters: `addCollection` is declared as a generic method, defining a `T` of its own. That `T` is not the same as the class `T`, hence the error message. Remove the `<T>` at its beginning, you don't need it.

Comment: I can't post a full answer right now, but just think about this: suppose you replace the strings in the `getCollection` calls with user provided strings. The compiler can't predict what that value will be. How can the compiler know your code doesn't break?? (This is **not** the problem itself, just a hint that what you're trying to do doesn't make sense as it is...)

Comment: @eran I have edited the suggestion you gave me.  The error moved to the two addCollection/2 calls in the `test()` method.  I had decided to move that information to the main method to make it more readable (and remove the `test()`method), but in the main method it doesn't give me any error.  That's weird.

Comment: Your test method is inside the class. You pass two types of sets to addCollection, non of which related to T. Now, even if the class had occasionally been instantiated with `Foo` or `Bar`, it's never for both. Further, due to type erasure, only one instance of `test` is generated, and its code must work for every `T`. On main, you're passing different sets to different objects, each instantiated with a type that matches the set's - hence it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class objects (runtime types) of the classes for your map keys:

```
class TryingSomething {
    private Map<Class<?>, Set<?>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> void addCollection(Set<T> s, Class<T> clazz){
        map.put(clazz, s);
    }

    public void test(){
        Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>();
        Set<Bar> bar = new HashSet<Bar>();
        addCollection(foo, Foo.class);
        addCollection(bar, Bar.class);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Set<T> getCollections(Class<T> clazz){
        return (Set<T>)this.map.get(clazz);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        TryingSomething t = new TryingSomething();
        Set<Foo> foo = new HashSet<Foo>();
        Set<Bar> bar = new HashSet<Bar>();
        t.addCollection(foo, Foo.class);
        t.addCollection(bar, Bar.class);
        Set<Foo> fooList = t.getCollections(Foo.class);
        Set<Bar> barList = t.getCollections(Bar.class);
    }

}

class Foo{
}

class Bar{
}
```

The class `TryingSomething` shouldn't be generic because you want to store sets of arbitrary types (chosen dynamically at runtime). Note that this implementation does not check if an inserted set actually contains objects of the specified type at all (neither at insertion nor at retrieval) - the reponsibility here lies with the user of this container class.